# Move many pictures/etc from Android to Linux, without a USB cable

Tags: gratis, android, ubuntu, debian, data-transfer

Every few days, I want to move all pictures from my Android phone to my Linux laptop.

In the past I was [using the USB cable](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/51165/move-files-from-android-configurable-list-of-directories-command-line), it worked great but unfortunately my current phone's USB port is defective so I can't use a USB cable. I don't want to transfer files via the Internet because mobile data is costly. That leaves me with Bluetooth and ad-hoc WiFi, I guess.

I am looking for a tool that would allow me to quickly (I mean, with as few manual operations as possible) transfer all files found in a dozen of folders such as `sdcard/DCIM/Camera` or `sdcard/Pictures/Messenger`, to a predefined folder on my Linux laptop.

Many of these folders contain only a few pictures, so transfer bitrate is less important than the time it takes to actually perform the whole action.

I would rather avoid [WiFi Direct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi_Direct) because [its installation on Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/258027/how-to-get-wifi-direct-wifi-p2p-on-my-hp-dm1-laptop) looks complex (recompiling core parts of the networking libraries).

Gratis, ideally open source.

Answer (score 1):

Try **[KDE Connect](https://github.com/KDE/kdeconnect-kde)**.

Quoting from the readme

> - Shared clipboard: copy and paste between your phone and your computer (or any other device).
> - Notification sync: Read and reply to your Android notifications from the desktop.
> - **Share files and URLs instantly from one device to another including some filesystem integration.**
> - Multimedia remote control: Use your phone as a remote for Linux media players.
> - Virtual touchpad: Use your phone screen as your computer's touchpad and keyboard.
> - Presentation remote: Advance your presentation slides straight from your phone.
>
> All this is done completely wirelessly, utilising TLS encryption.

Comment: According to https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/6ggb36/kde_connect_works_over_bluetooth_now_please_help/ I need to recompile it with a certain flag to work over Bluetooth. Is it what you mean? But then some people in that thread say that using Bluetooth for file transfer is not reliable, actually the bluetooth branch is still considered unstable: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=330536 Would you mind describing the KDE Connect settings you suggest that works without USB and without an Internet connection? Thanks :-)

Comment: I was able to use KDE Connect using Android's WiFi tethering feature :-) I then used the Android app to share the whole phone's storage, installed Dolphin, and my files appear in Dolphin. Now I have to cut/paste manually for each of the dozen of folders, slow but it works :-)

Comment: Truth is I've never used KDE Connect to transfer files, it's the other features I use. Sounds like you've rigged something that works. Hopefully someone else has a better recommendation. Peace.

Comment: A huge problem I just discovered is that KDE Connect has corrupted about 10% of my pictures. It means that many of my pictures are lost :'-(

Comment: Noooo. Nicolas, terribly sorry for your loss.

Comment: Apparently I was hit by this bug: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=405847 hopefully someone will fix it soon :-)

Comment: LIfe in FOSS world... Al'hamdulilah as they say in Arabic (All praise to God).